# Regenerative braking on BLDC motor

Tags: microcontroller, stm32, embedded, brushless-dc-motor, programming

I am trying to design regen Braking for BLDC motor controller I used three switch topologies for regenerative braking.
[image]

In three switch method, high-side MOSFET S1, S3, and S5 are kept OFF and low-side MOSFET S2, S4, and S6 are operated in PWM switching mode at the same time in each commutation state. I tested it on NO load condition it worked well when I tested it on Load condition when the regenerative brake is applied motor gets stopped with noise but on NO load, the motor doesn’t produce noise. Can anyone help me know the cause of the noise that produces during regenerative braking on loaded condition?

oscilloscope image on NO load condition
channel-1 (yellow) Low-side gate pulse on the regenerative brake is applied.
channel-2 (green) DC current waveform.
[image]

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "Load"?